# Propagating zsh window title through tmux, then ssh, to terminal emulator/window manager

Tags: ssh, terminal, zsh, tmux, kitty

My zsh automatically sets my terminal emulator (kitty)'s window title to my current working directory, or whatever program is currently running within it.  However, when I ssh to a remote host and run then run `tmux new`, this stops happening - my window title gets frozen to the last command that was run before tmux started.  When in a normal ssh terminal, this doesn't happen, nor does it happen when running tmux locally.  Only the combination of ssh+tmux will cause this problem.

Any ideas for things to try to debug this issue?  Options to set, or ways to see what the terminal title should be set as from within zsh or tmux?

My tmux config (and other configs) are at https://github.com/kovasap/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf.